# WCF security negotiation exception

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

We are using below mentioned security configuration for our services

Configuration:

```
<security mode="Message">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
</security>
```

In our local network while accessing services we getting below exception from some of the clients:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.
ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, Sspi
NegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
```

I have collected the WCF traces, but it is not helpful. I am guessing that windows kerberos is not able to authenticate windows identity. I have verified that client machine/logged in user details are available in ADS and both server and clients are in same domain.

Please let me know if you have any solutions for this problem.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be time skew. Try to see if the affected clients clock is different.

Otherwise. If you can attach Visual Studio debugger to the client code, and disable "just my code", you can break on the internal exceptions in WCF. By default WCF hides all internal exceptions.

Comment: Both server and clients have the same time.

Comment: try to add tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to the client. Notice that the msdn example includes System.IdentiyModel.